# How do I decide a level and mechanic for a new Spell Infection spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, homebrew

I have a player that loves loves making new spells.  He got the idea to "infect" a spell, specifically Fog Cloud cast by an ally. The idea is to change or add a property to the spell, such as add a sleep ability to the Fog, or various other changes.

I'm at a loss as to how to generate a level or success condition for such a spell.
Are there any precedents for such a spell?
The only one I can find is Spellcurse, but that doesn't seem directly applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume you *are* familiar with the guidelines for [spell research](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/downtime/#TOC-Research-a-Spell) and [new spells designing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Research-and-Designing-Spells). As such, I will address how I would do that on a game balance perspective.

[Sleep](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sleep/) causes a fairly powerful negative condition, [helpless](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Helpless), and it basically puts those affected out of combat. But it has limitations, it cannot affect a fair share of creatures in the game, like the undead, without designing a character specifically for it.  Sleep spells are one of the classic examples of **save or suck** effects, where the target either makes his saving throw, or he is out of combat/severely crippled. Which is why the designers decided to put HD limitations on nearly all Sleep spells and similar effects.

The spell that is most similar with an *area* effect of Sleep is [Symbol of Sleep](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/symbol-of-sleep/), which is a 5th level spell for clerics and wizards. And even this has a HD limit (10 HD or less), but affected area is 60 feet and it can affect up to 150 hit points worth of creatures.

Now, [Fog Cloud](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fog-cloud/) (2nd) has *several* variations, most of which add some negative condition or damage to those inside the spell effect. To name a few:

- [Solid Fog](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/solid-fog/) (4th), hampers movement and causes attack penalties.
- [Cloudkill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cloudkill/) (5th), 1-6 HD are killed, stronger creatures take constitution damage per round.
- [Acid Fog](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/acid-fog/) (6h), on top of Solid Fog effects, cause 2d6 acid damage per round.
- [Incendiary Cloud](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/incendiary-cloud/) (8th), deals 6d6 fire damage each round.

The effects of a cloud that would put those inside to sleep sounds similar to both Cloud Kill and Symbol of Sleep, and as such, I would make it a **6th level spell**. Will save or put to sleep if they take a breath inside the spell effect, but once they make their save, they are safe.

I said all this so you have the **spell relative power** in mind when deciding if you should allow your players to combine two low-level spells to obtain a greater spell effect. The [Blood of the Elements](http://paizo.com/products/btpy978p?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Blood-of-the-Elements) player companion added the [Elemental Commixture](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/teamwork-feats/elemental-commixture-teamwork/) teamwork feat, which allows two casters to combine the elemental effects of spells to obtain new effects. These effects are (mostly) minor and temporary (targets go prone, or are blinded for a round, or will catch fire, etc), but as such, they also do not affect the level of the spell being cast.

There is also a third party feat called [Merge Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/rite-publishing/metamagic-feats-3rd-party-rite-publishing/merge-spells-metamagic/) from [Steven D. Russel](http://paizo.com/people/Qwilion)'s [Feats 101](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8b6a?Feats-101), which applies both spell effects into a single cast at cost of increasing the spell level by 2.

So, I would create a new teamwork feat called **Spell Infusion** (the name is similar in theme to the abilities of a [Kineticist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/)), which both casters would have to obtain, and by reading an action, they would be able to cast both spells at the same time on the same targets, adding the effects of the second spell on top of the effects of the first spell. The advantages of doing that is using the area and targets of the area spell. The targets would still be allowed two saves (if both spells allowed a save) to negate or reduce the effects, and the duration would have to be tracked separately or it would affect game balance. This would not increase the level of the spells being cast.

Note that on your scenario, first casting Fog Cloud on an area would prevent the other caster from casting Sleep on the same area, due to lack of visibility to pick the area and targets. The feat would also help against that issue.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with spell research, but this however is extremely thorough.  Thanks.  My initial plan was to make it concentration and force and expensive material comp.  however the feat is much more 'realistic'

Comment: Nitpick to your last paragraph: Area spells such as Sleep don't require line-of-sight.

Comment: You can affect targets you cannot see, but you must see the point of origin for any ranged spell: *You must designate the point of origin for such an effect, but you need not have line of effect (see below) to all portions of the effect.*

Comment: Its also on the line of effect rules: *You must have a clear line of effect to any target that you cast a spell on or to any space in which you wish to create an effect.*